# Permanently unhide hidden files MAC Mountain Lion to Mavericks

Tags: mac, data-transfer

I have a mac user which I am rebuilding a machine for.

He is currently on Mountain Lion and will be upgraded to Mavericks.
The issue I am having is with the transfer of his data. All our machines here have two partitions. 1st partition is the for OS and the other partition is for users data.

I have looked at this persons data folder but his files were hidden. I have run a command in terminal to view the hidden files and have copied them to an external hard drive.

I have now gone to transfer the data yet on the hard drive the files are hidden again. These files shouldnt be hidden is there anyway to change the format of these files to not be hidden types at the moment the file icons are displayed but slightly transparent.

Any ideas how to permanently format these to be unhidden files?

Answer (score 0):

As Mac is Unix based, hidden files should simply be those whose filename starts with a fullstop/period character '.'

For example, renaming .myhiddenfile to myhiddenfile should make it visible.